# PHP: How to make an array by a comma separated string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code: `37,40,42,46,49,54,56,57` now I wanna separate each number and convert all numbers to an Array.
The array that I want is:

```
array(37,40,42,46,49,54,56,57)
```

Comment: it is in a array. Do you mean you want an associative array where you can access a specific value by calling?

Comment: You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Please do more research in the future, before asking a question.

Comment: Is this code of yours a string?

Comment: explode is sooo last year ;p https://3v4l.org/Ov33P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this:

```
$string = "37,40,42,46,49,54,56,57";
$array = explode("," , $string);
```